# c++ Перебор чисел с плавающей точкой

Tags: c++, double, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Нужно узнать какие числа составляет число N из чисел a и b

к a и b должно с помощью цикла прибавлятся по 0.1
Делал что то типо такого:

```
double P, R;

cin >> P;
cin >> R;

for (double i = 0.1; i <= P; i = i + 0.1) {
    for (double j = 0.1; j <= P; j = j + 0.1) {
        double s = i + j;
        if (s == P) {
            cout << i << " " << j << endl;
        }
    }
}
cout << "END" << endl;
```

Но так как у числа не просто 0.1 а 0.1000000000...56 из за этого число переходит и не находит все цифры которые могут получится при сложении этих двух, особенно обычных напрмер для 13 (7 и 6)

Comment: а `R` вам зачем вообще?

Comment: «какие числа составляет число N из чисел a и b»  Странная постановка задачи. да и перебор странноват. Когда почините сравнение, вариантов будет не слишком много? `0.1+(P-0.1); 0.2+(P-0.2); ...;(P-0.2)+0.2; (P-0.1)+0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во-первых `double` сравнивать можете так:

```
abs(s - P) < 0.0001
```

где `0.0001` - это заданная для вашей задачи точность, написал от балды, можно поставить что-то типа `1e-10`

во-вторых, чтобы точность проседала меньше, лучше не накапливать ошибку через сложение `double` чисел, а

1. сделать цикл по целым числам

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < int(P / 0.1) + 1;  i ++)
   ```
2. вычислять конкретный `double` для конкретного `i`

   ```
    const value_i = 0.1 * i;
   ```